# When might one use attribute targets?

Tags: c#

When might one use attribute prefixes such as class:, return: and module: ?

I haven't yet seen anyone use these prefixes so I was wondering where they could be used.

Example

```
namespace NameSpace {

    class Program {

        [return: Description("Returns true if is in a valid state")]
        [method: Description("Determines xyz")]
        public void IsValid) {
          return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have never even heard about people using those. I believe most C# programmers would use the `///` to make a `summary` of the following method

Comment: @Ziga I'm simply using the Description attribute as an example. You can use other attributes. I'm more interested in the attribute targets that the attributes are prefixed with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which explains where attribute targets could be useful and what problem they address. I remember using those back in the good old days before ASP.NET MVC was out and I was writing some [MonoRail applications](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2010/01/20/whatrsquos-new-in-monorail-2-dot-0). The `[return: JSONReturnBinder]` allows to specify a binder for the return type of a controller action instead of input parameters.

Comment: Looks like targets are applied to attributes by default anyway except for a couple of exceptions. Thanks for that handy link.